# Regex doubt in Android (Java) code

Tags: java, regex

Can someone tell me exactly what is this regex doing?

```
new StringTokenizer(string,":/.@\\;,+ ");
```

I could not understand the exact meaning of this Regex, though it looks like something to do with splitting a string based on special characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`StringTokenizer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) does **not** use regular expressions. The second parameter is a list of characters to be used as separators between tokens.

The JavaDoc says:

> `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use [the `split` method of `String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) or the `java.util.regex` package instead.

Answer (score 1):

`StringTokenizer` does not use regular expressions. The second argument is just the list of delimiters that it will use by default to split apart the string.

Answer (score 0):

There is no regex in this code. the second argument is contains the list of the delimiters used to tokenize the string.